# ROR conditional if statement not executing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ibm-midrange

I have this section in model:

**Updated 07-25**

```
   if sign_on.acctypw1.strip == "DS" or sign_on.acctypw1.strip == "DSD"         
        rec = SignOn.find_by_userw1!(login)            
        webid = rec.prfdstw1               
    end 
        weboel23 = Weboel23.first(:conditions => {:act223 => webid}, :select => "emal23")   


    approval0=Weboel23.find_by_account0(!webid)
    approval1=Weboel23.find_by_account1(!webid)
    approval2=Weboel23.find_by_account2(!webid)
    approval3=Weboel23.find_by_account3(!webid)
    approval4=Weboel23.find_by_account4(!webid)
```

**this code does appear to be working however when:**

```
  sign_on.acctypw1.strip == "DSD"
```

**this code doesn't seem to run:**

```
webid = rec.prfdstw1 weboel23 = Weboel23.first(:conditions => {:act223 => webid}, :select =>     "emal23") approval0=Weboel23.get_email_by_account0(webid) 
approval1=Weboel23.get_email_by_account1(webid) approval2=Weboel23.get_email_by_account2(webid)     
approval3=Weboel23.get_email_by_account3(webid) approval4=Weboel23.get_email_by_account4(webid)
```

**when it is:**

```
 sign_on.acctypw1.strip == "DS"
```

**it will run and return proper result.  I need both cases to execute. Any ideas??**

Comment: ruby 1.9.2p0  rails 3.2.13

Comment: *** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.2.13, 3.2.9, 2.3.10, 2.3.8)
actionpack (3.2.13, 3.2.9, 2.3.10, 2.3.8)
activemodel (3.2.13, 3.2.9)
activerecord (3.2.13, 3.2.9, 2.3.10, 2.3.8, 1.15.6)
activerecord-odbc-adapter (2.0)
activeresource (3.2.13, 3.2.9, 2.3.10, 2.3.8)
activesupport (3.2.13, 3.2.9, 2.3.10)
arel (3.0.2, 1.0.1)

Comment: authlogic (2.1.6)
builder (3.0.4, 2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.2)
columnize (0.3.6)
daemon_controller (0.2.5)
erubis (2.7.0, 2.6.6)
fastthread (1.0.7)
file-tail (1.0.5)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.1, 0.4.1)
ibm_db (2.5.5)
journey (1.0.4)
json (1.7.5)
mail (2.5.3, 2.4.4, 2.2.7)
memcache-client (1.8.5)
mime-types (1.16)
mini_magick (3.1)
minitest (1.6.0)
multi_json (1.5.0)
mysql (2.8.1)
odbc-rails (1.5)
passenger (3.0.1)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.4.5, 1.4.1, 1.2.1, 1.1.0)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-mount (0.6.13)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)

Comment: rack-test (0.6.2, 0.5.6)
rails (2.3.10, 2.3.8)
railties (3.2.13, 3.2.9)
rake (0.8.7)
rbx-require-relative (0.0.9)
rdoc (3.12, 2.5.8)
rubygems-update (1.3.7)
sprockets (2.2.2)
spruz (0.2.2)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.1)
subexec (0.0.4)
text-format (1.0.0)
text-hyphen (1.0.0)
thor (0.16.0, 0.14.3)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.8)
tzinfo (0.3.35, 0.3.23)
us_states_select (1.2.0)
wicked_pdf (0.9.0)

Comment: Does anyone have ideas fr the above?